# Need a way to regulate current and voltage in CCCV but portable

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, current-limiting, constant-current, over-voltage-protection

I have a project in embedded systems that requires charging a 14S lipo battery from a 60V regulator/alternator supply (an RC vehicle), the lipo gets to 99% capacity around 58.8V and the circuit limit is between 4-6A. The BMS can only cut the circuit once the current and voltage exceeds limits meaning the battery never charges unless I regulate both current and voltage.

I am trying to put something between the 60V and the battery that acts as a CCCV regulator while it charges. Holding the current at 5A until it reaches 58V then holding the voltage there as the current decreases. Issue is it has to be portable and small sized or it wont fit in the vehicle. Power electronics really is not my field so if anyone can provide a good suggestion I'd be great.

[image: basic diagram]

Comment: Welcome! Can you draw a block diagram of how everything is connected?

Comment: What you need is a 14S li-ion charger which can take 60 V input.